# Add images in listView Android

Tags: java, android, image, sqlite, listview

I'm saving the images name in the database and these images are saved in the drawable, now i want to assign for each item an image from the database according to the item name, i want to compare it with the database.

In database where the image field and the category type (will be retrieved in the list view)

and here is the code for retrieving the category type into list view:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.my_profile, c, from, to);  

       ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);  

       list.setAdapter(adapter);  
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {      

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ShowWhereToGo.class); 
                myIntent.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); // display SubView.class               }
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void onItemClick1(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }});

}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ @user2870902 refer this link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `custom list row` to show images in `ListView`
you can refer this [LINK](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom list.You may refer to the following link:

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/

Hope this will help in resolving your trouble :)

Comment: but my list is retrieved from database .. not from array string, what should i do ?